# Jquery Mobile - submitting search from

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery mobile and have a search button

```
    <form class="search">
        <input type="search" name="search" id="search-basic" value="" />
    </form>
```

When I submit the form, it's automatically reloading the page with `?search=xxx` string on the end, so `mob.site.com/?search=wibble`for example.

I actually need the search feature to simply load a new page of `mob.site.com/search?search=wibble` instead of loading on the same page and I can't find how to do this.

Is there an easy way to overwrite the default destination function?

ta

Comment: Would action="/search" in the form not work?

Comment: okay, now i feel stupid :) Too tunnel visioned to see the obvious. Please post as answer and I'll give you the credit

Comment: No worries, it happens to the all of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add action="/search"

```
<form action="/search" class="search">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search-basic" value="" />
</form>
```